# Show differences with another user in TFS

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have Eclipse Neon.

I want to show differences with my file and same file in another computer/user which I have permission to.

Can I do that? I know it's possible in Intellij.

Comment: Comparing 2 files is not a TFS question. This is without merit.

Comment: I want to check same as in intellij or visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends the user is using a sever workspace or a local workspace. You could use [tf status command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/status-command) to display information about pending changes to files and folders in one or more workspaces.

> You can also use this command to view pending changes in a remote
>   server workspace (for example, changes made by another user on another
>   dev machine) by using the /collection, **/user**, and /workspace
>   options. **However, you cannot view pending changes in a remote local
>   workspace.**

Then you could just use a diff tool to show the difference.

Comment: from eclipse it impossible?

Comment: @user7294900 There is a 3-party tool called TFS power tools. You could click the File > Source Control > Find in Source Control > Status to get the same thing. However it's only available from IDE in Visual Studio. It's not support on eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the source tree, and choose "View History." This will list all changesets that have been checked in to source control. You can right-click the changeset, and select "Compare." This will provide a dialog that lets you select the file to compare against.

Comment: I want to to know before check in. The file is still checkout

Comment: The file in another locked computer with user y